# Resources for learning to use javascript with asp.net-mvc 3 and cshtml (razor)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a pretty good understanding of MVC 3 model, but are not as familiar with using JavaScript in html razor (cshtml) - can any kind soul give tips on good resources to learn just Javascript linked to Racor and microsoft mvc 3

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean linked to razor? Javascript is independent of razor.

Comment: Yes iknow - i meant, i want to learn creating web apps with Javascript, and my enviroment is aps.net-mvc - razor. (im a old school windows app programmer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basics of JavaScript are here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/

The language specification is here: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm but it's a complete overkill IMO.

MVC 3 isn't dependant on JavaScript or vice-versa.

Once you get to grips with JavaScript, I recommend looking at jQuery: http://jquery.com/